# Showing records with datetime columns in calendar format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-pivot

I'm trying to resolve a problem using SQL Server.

I have records with "from" and "to" datetime columns and states. They are indeed hotel rooms reservation records.

```
id   UnitId       From             To          State
1      1        2021-07-01      2021-07-10        1 (reserved)
1      2        2021-07-15      2021-08-15        2 (occupied)
1      1        2021-07-11      2021-07-25        1
```

I need to show them in a calendar format

```
Unit     20210701  20210702  20210703  ....... 20210711  20210712 ....
1           R          R         R
2                                                 O         O
```

I can go unit by unit and day by day and search the unit state on that day and put R or O.

But this takes a long time with several units and long periods to show in the calendar.

Maybe can someone give any ideas how can a convert the reservation records and display them as calendar?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am afraid in this case you need a dynamic pivot

Comment: There are 365 days in a year, you want that many columns??

Comment: No, probably they will check a month or two. The selection is dynamically from the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide you a dynamic PIVOT. I Used the data you have given.

```
DECLARE @SQL  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @cols_ AS  vARCHAR(MAX) 

  --Making the column list dynamically 
 SELECT @cols_   = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME( REPLACE([T2].[From],'-','') )  
           FROM  [CalenderData] [T2]                
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')             


 print @cols_
--preparing PIVOT query dynamically. 

  SET @SQL = ' SELECT     
             pivoted.UnitID
              ,'+@cols_+'   
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT 
                
     [T2].[UnitID], 
     [T2].[From],
     CASE WHEN [T2].[State] = 2 THEN ''R'' 
     ELSE ''O'' END AS  [Status]
   FROM   [CalenderData] [T2] 

  ) AS [p]
  PIVOT
  (
     MIN([P].[Status]) 
     FOR  [P].[From]  IN (' + @cols_ + ')
  ) AS pivoted;
  ';

 --PRINT( @SQL) this will help you to Check the generated query from Dynamic Code
 EXEC (@SQL)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @Diego Let me know if you need any help or any alteration to this query